# OOP Dependency Inversion Principle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made an example for learning [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) in JavaScript OOP programming .

```
String.prototype.ucfirst = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

function textHandler(){

    this.printRedbox = function( ){
        return ' Red Box text ';
    }

    this.printBluebox = function( ){
        return ' Blue Box text ';
    }
};


function htmlHandler( handler ){

    var block = [],
        box  = document.getElementById('container');

    this.boxContentHandler =  handler ;

    this.setType = function( handler ){
        this.boxContentHandler = handler
    };

    this.appendBlock = function( html ){

        block.push( html );
        box.innerHTML = block.join('');
    };

    this.printBox = function ( action ){

        var title = this.printTitle() ,
            text  = this.boxContentHandler[ 'print'+ action.ucfirst() ](),
            html  = '<div class="box '+ action.replace('box','') +'">'
                        +   title + text
                    +'</div>' ;

        this.appendBlock( html );
    };

    this.printTitle = function( ) {
            return 'Title ' + block.length + ' <br />';
    };
};
```

Here I am doing the action handling part

```
var htmlHandle = new htmlHandler(  new textHandler()  );

document.getElementById('bluebox').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    htmlHandle.printBox(  this.id );
},false );            

document.getElementById('redbox').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    htmlHandle.printBox(  this.id );
},false );
```

I would like to know, is there a way to make it better. Did I miss anything here ?

Comment: Why is the DOM element created inside `htmlHandle` (rather than injected)? Why are you creating HTML from strings? Why are you joining strings for property lookup? You might want to read http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes that code is in JAVA . I only know server side langauge PHP . On this example I am trying make html string . and collect them into array.. on clicking button the innerHTML changes `box.innerHTML = block.join('')`

Comment: @rab: I suppose you mean JavaScript, not Java, right?

Comment: @MichaelZedeler yes in `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a decent way to implement Dependency Inversion, from the standpoint of your implementing classes. The only improvements I would recommend is to find a good class library that does the lookup of dependencies for you.

Really Inversion of Control/Dependency Inversion involves several parts:

1. Writing your classes so that they receive their dependencies via one of three methods:

   1. Constructor injection (like you have) `new Foo(x)`
   2. Property injection `a.foo = b`
   3. Setter injection `a.setFoo(b)`
2. An object factory that can turn a class name in the form of a String into a new object
3. An dependency resolver that does the lookup of dependencies and injects them into a new object
4. A "container" object allowing you to configure your dependencies and wire your classes together

I've created [Hypodermic](https://github.com/gburghardt/hypodermic) for this purpose, though I think it should be refactored to separate the "container" from the "dependency resolver" functionality. I would be interested in finding out if there are other Dependency Injection libraries out there for JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

From a once over;

- `ucfirst` <- not a great name
- Single comma separated `var` statements <- nice
- Consider using `use strict`
- You need more comments explaining how you made DIP work, honestly I am not convinced that this is a good example of DIP ( I could be wrong )
- <s>The link between the `id` and the function name makes for brittle code</s> <- Apparently that's the point ;)
- You are not using `setType` anywhere in your example
- `htmlHandler` <- probably should have been `boxHandler` given how everything inside references `box` and `block`